# Limit of the Casselman–Shalika Formula for the Spherical Whittaker Function

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, characters

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$Consider $G = \GL_{r+1}(F)$, where $F$ is a local non-archimedian field with the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_F$ and the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, and let $q = \lvert\mathcal{O}_F/\mathfrak{p}\rvert$. The group $G$ has unramified principal series representations $(\pi_z, V_z)$ parametrized by $z \in \mathbf{C}^{r+1}$. Let $\Phi$ be the root system of $G$ (which is $A_r$), and $\Phi^+$ be the positive roots.

Let $W\colon G \to \mathbf{C}$ be the spherical Whittaker function on $(\pi_z, V_z)$. It is enough to calculate $W$ on the diagonal elements $\varpi^\lambda$, and the celebrated Casselman–Shalika formula (Theorem 5.4 of [1]) gives the explicit expression
$$
W(\varpi^\lambda) = \prod_{\alpha \in \Phi^+}(1-q^{-1}z^{\alpha})s_\lambda(z),
$$
where $s_\lambda$ is the Schur polynomial. Note that the product in the formula is a deformed Weyl denominator. More generally, for a split reductive group $G$ over $F$, the values of the spherical Whittaker functions on the diagonal element can be evaluated as the product of the deformed Weyl denominator and the character of the highest weight representation of the dual Langlands group.

If, formally, $q \to \infty$, the deformed denominator disappears, and the formula reduces to the character (e.g. Schur polynomial for $\GL_{r+1}$). This reduction is consistent with the recent combinatorial evaluation of the Whittaker functions in terms of partition functions of 6-vertex models, where after the reduction, the character is given by 5-vertex models [2].

My question is

> What is the meaning of the limit $q \to \infty$ on the representation theory side? Why does the limit of the spherical Whittaker functions, as the cardinality of the residue field goes to infinity, converge to the character of the corresponding highest weight representation of the dual group?

[1] Casselman, William, and Joseph Shalika. "The unramified principal series of $ p $-adic groups. II. The Whittaker function." Compositio Mathematica 41.2 (1980): 207-231. http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1980__41_2_207_0

[2] Brubaker, Ben, Daniel Bump, and Solomon Friedberg. "Schur polynomials and the Yang-Baxter equation." Communications in mathematical physics 308.2 (2011): 281. https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0911